# Futrinka street and the plausiblity of comfortably habitable giant-pumpkin houses

Tags: science-based, flora, engineering

So, there was this pupet show about two characters, Mazsola and Tádé. They lived in a BIG pumpkin, that had been hollowed out and repurposed as a house.

[image]

It looked something like this. Now, I kinda like the idea of a big pumpkin house, especially if one was to carve the windows so the lights would resemble the face of a Donald Trump during night.

Anyway, it got me thinking,

- would a giant (8 meters in height) pumpkin be possible without any
  real modification to its flesh and walls? Probably, also, see how I
  didn't say anything about the stem? That's my loophole.
- **Could you hollow it out an live inside of it for a long and comfortable (aside from having to collect twigs and carry fagots around)
  time?**

Answer (score 3):

Pumpkins can get very large.  It is not clear how large; over the last decade immense pumpkins are being grown - over 1000 kg.

That is a far cry from 8 meters.  A problem is the water weight of the flesh - it will stress the lower parts and crush it.

The solution of course is to grow these truly monstrous pumpkins in a zero-gravity environment, so they are liberated from their weight.  Pumpkin growing satellite greenhouses will also be free of pests and the possibility of adverse weather.

It is not clear there would be any limit on the size of a zero-gravity pumpkins.  8 meters might turn out to be small.  To use it as a house you would want to hollow it out and dry it in orbit - fortunately the vacuum of space will do this admirably and quickly for you.

A waterproof coating will help with durability once back on earth, or you could replace it every season with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

you would no doubt need to wax it in order to keep moisture inside like varnishing wood.  you could hollow out the pumpkin easily it is already mostly hallow just seeds with a bit of meat. but yes posible and easy.